# Printing ParenctChildren Hierarchy using Kncokout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, grid

Need help in printing data in form of parent children hierarchy.

```
<!--Parent Modal--->
function serviceList(serviceName,serviceDuration,serviceDefaultCost,serviceId,serviceTaskList)
{
    this.serviceName=ko.observable(serviceName);
    this.serviceDuration=ko.observable(serviceDuration);
    this.serviceDefaultCost=ko.observable(serviceDefaultCost);
    this.serviceId=ko.observable(serviceId);
    this.serviceTaskList=ko.utils.arrayMap(serviceTaskList,function(item){
        return new servicesTaskList(item.serviceTaskId,item.skillId,item.skillName,item.boothType,item.facilityId,item.facilityName,item.serviceName,item.serviceTaskDuration,item.serviceTaskOrder,item.serviceTaskName,item.deleteFlag);
    });
}

<!--Children Modal--->
function servicesTaskList(serviceTaskId,skillId,skillName,boothType,facilityId,facilityName,serviceName,serviceTaskDuration,serviceTaskOrder,serviceTaskName,deleteFlag)
{
    this.serviceTaskId= ko.observable(serviceTaskId);
    this.skillId= ko.observable(skillId);
    this.skillName= ko.observable(skillName);
    this.boothType= ko.observable(skillName);
    this.facilityId= ko.observable(facilityId);
    this.facilityName= ko.observable(facilityName);
    this.serviceName= ko.observable(serviceName);
    this.serviceTaskDuration= ko.observable(serviceTaskDuration);
    this.serviceTaskOrder= ko.observable(serviceTaskOrder);
    this.serviceTaskName= ko.observable(serviceTaskName);
    this.deleteFlag= ko.observable(deleteFlag);

}
```

serviceTaskList is an other modal that consists of child data after every parent iteration Neeed to print children then again parent and its children and so on..

- serviceName1  serviceDuration1 serviceDefaultCost1 serviceId1 serviceTaskList1

  - skillId1 skillName boothType facilityId facilityName serviceTaskDuration
- skillId2 skillName boothType facilityId facilityName serviceTaskDuration
- skillId3 skillName boothType facilityId facilityName serviceTaskDuration

serviceName2  serviceDuration2 serviceDefaultCost2 serviceId2 serviceTaskList2

- skillId1 skillName boothType facilityId facilityName serviceTaskDuration

skillId2 skillName boothType facilityId facilityName serviceTaskDuration

skillId3 skillName boothType facilityId facilityName serviceTaskDuration

Please anyone help me your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extremely basic html model for you to go off of.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Parent">
 <li data-bind="text: serviceName1() + ' ' + serviceDuration1() + ' ' + serviceDefaultCost1() + ' ' + serviceId1() + ' ' + serviceTaskList1()"></li>
 <li>
     <ul data-bind="foreach: Child">
         <li data-bind="text: skillId3() + ' ' +  skillName() + ' ' +  boothType() + ' ' +  facilityId() + ' ' +  facilityName() + ' ' +  serviceTaskDuration() + ' ' + "></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```